# Who are the thieves and robbers that have come before Jesus?

Tags: john, referent-identification

John 10:8 says

> All who have come before me are thieves and robbers, but the sheep have not listened to them.

My question is: Who are the ones mentioned in this passage that have come before Jesus and are thieves and robbers?

I can identify thieves and robbers nowadays, but before? Who are they?